# Django Error u"'polls" is not a registered namespace

Tags: django, namespaces

Yesterday I was working on my first app using this tutorial. It's a Poll and Choice app.
The first page displays the question and when you click on the question it's suppose to display choices which you can vote on them.

I had great people who helped me yesterday and told me to use namespace. I've read the namespace tutorial and tried to apply my knowledge
to the scenario but it isn't working so far.

This is my error when I click on the questions which is the first page.

```
 NoReverseMatch at /polls/5/

 u"'polls" is not a registered namespace

 Request Method:    GET
 Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/5/
 Django Version:    1.4.3
 Exception Type:    NoReverseMatch
 Exception Value:   

 u"'polls" is not a registered namespace

 Exception Location:    C:\hp\bin\Python\Lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py in render, line 424
 Python Executable:     C:\hp\bin\Python\python.exe
 Python Version:    2.5.2
 Python Path:   

 ['C:\\djcode\\mysite',
  'C:\\hp\\bin\\Python\\python25.zip',
  'C:\\hp\\bin\\Python\\DLLs',
  'C:\\hp\\bin\\Python\\lib',
  'C:\\hp\\bin\\Python\\lib\\plat-win',
  'C:\\hp\\bin\\Python\\lib\\lib-tk',
  'C:\\hp\\bin\\Python',
  'C:\\hp\\bin\\Python\\lib\\site-packages',
  'C:\\hp\\bin\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
  'C:\\hp\\bin\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
  'C:\\hp\\bin\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']

 Server time:   Fri, 15 Feb 2013 21:04:10 +1100
 Error during template rendering

 In template C:\djcode\mysite\myapp\templates\myapp\detail.html, error at line 5
 u"'polls" is not a registered namespace
 1  <h1>{{ poll.question }}</h1>
 2  
 3  {% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
 4  
 5  {% url 'polls:vote' poll.id %}
 6  {% csrf_token %}
 7  {% for choice in poll.choice_set.all %}
 8  <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
 9  <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
 10     {% endfor %}
 11     <input type="submit" value="Vote" />
 12     </form>
```

Now I know the problems are hidden in detail.html, my main urls and my app called myapp URLCONF and views.py

Now My main URLconf are:
C:\djcode\mysite\mysite

```
 from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
 from django.contrib import admin
 from django.conf import settings
 # Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
 # from django.contrib import admin
 admin.autodiscover()

 urlpatterns = patterns('',
     #url(r'^polls/', include('myapp.urls')),
     url(r'^polls/', include('myapp.urls', namespace='polls')),                   
     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
 )
```

My app folder is called myapp and this is myapp URLconf:
C:\djcode\mysite\myapp

```
 from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
 from django.contrib import admin
 from django.conf import settings

 from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

 urlpatterns = patterns('myapp.views',
     url(r'^$', 'index'),
     url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', 'detail'),
     url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$', 'results'),
     url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', 'vote'),


)
```

My views.py inside myapp are:

```
 from django.http import HttpResponse
 from myapp.models import Poll ,choice
 from django.template import Context, loader
 from django.http import Http404
 from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
 from django.template import RequestContext

 def index(request):
     latest_poll_list = Poll.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
     return render_to_response('myapp/index.html', {'latest_poll_list': latest_poll_list})

 def results(request, poll_id):
     p = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
     return render_to_response('myapp/results.html', {'poll': p})

 def vote(request, poll_id):
     p = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
     try:
         selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
     except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
         # Redisplay the poll voting form.
         return render_to_response('myapp/detail.html', {
             'poll': p,
             'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
         }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
     else:
         selected_choice.votes += 1
         selected_choice.save()
         # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
    # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
         # user hits the Back button.
         return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myapp.views.results', args=(p.id,)))

 def detail(request, poll_id):
     p = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
     return render_to_response('myapp/detail.html', {'poll': p},
                                context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My detail.html 
C:\djcode\mysite\myapp\templates\myapp

```
 <h1>{{ poll.question }}</h1>

 {% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

 {% url 'polls:vote' poll.id %}
 {% csrf_token %}
 {% for choice in poll.choice_set.all %}
     <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
     <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
 {% endfor %}
 <input type="submit" value="Vote" />
 </form>
```

Comment: add `{% load url from future %}` at the top of your template or try removing the quotes surrounding `'polls:vote'` in your url tag

Comment: I tried it , it says TemplateSyntaxError at /polls/3/ . thank you for trying to help me

Comment: which version of django are you using, and have you tried just to add the template tag load url from future without changing the quotation?

Comment: Django Version:    1.4.3 , I had this error few days but I just ignored it but now I'm trying to figure out how to fix this.

Comment: @cathy , Last time I did it with the wrong version using python anywhere and I though I'll just ignore it but now i'm doing it with my computer . I don't know what to do , Can you help me !

Comment: Finish and fix, I send it already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
 from django.contrib import admin
 from django.conf import settings



 urlpatterns = patterns('myapp.views',
     url(r'^$', 'index', name="index"),
     url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', 'detail', name="detail"),
     url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$', 'results', name="results"),
     url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', 'vote', name="vote"),
)

----------------------------------    

 <h1>{{ poll.question }}</h1>

 {% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

 <form method="post" action="{% url myapp:vote poll.id %}">
 {% csrf_token %}
 {% for choice in poll.choice_set.all %}
     <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
     <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
 {% endfor %}
 <input type="submit" value="Vote" />
 </form>
```

Comment: Sorry , I posted this question again . The last time I posted it , I was using an online python called python anywhere and I was reading the wrong tutorial version but now i'm using my computer with the correct version and I still get this error .

Comment: nope it still doesn't work @cathy  . I think it's the detail.html but I don't know

Comment: Do you think it could be my setting.py?

Comment: I tried {% load url from future %} at the top of your template and removing the quotes from {% url 'polls:vote' poll.id %} but it just display syntax error

Comment: When you say different url . Do you mean I created an app called myapp?

Comment: yeah you have polls which is your namespace and myapp which is your views. You are just started learning django so to make you not confuse, don't make it different so that it is easy for you to run your app

Comment: should I change my namespace from polls into myapp and the detail?

Comment: If you change it, you have to change everything that have connection with that so additional errors again. Why not create other poll app again and make your mistake be correct.

Comment: I made this app like 7 times. 5 online using python anywhere and twice here.I changed my namespace before into myapp and the error is u"'myapp" is not a registered namespace . Do I have to also register the namespace with my myapp foldeR? urlconf @cathy

Comment: Ok just do this, change all your "polls" into "myapp", even your folder name must be myapp also

Comment: hey cathy@ is it because detail.html cannot reach the main url namespace?

Comment: NoReverseMatch at /polls/1/

    u"'myapp" is not a registered namespace

Comment: Ok I will just message you if I finish it

Comment: Cathy Do I replace all the files with my file?

Comment: Just merge it,,Copy the modified mysite and save where your current mysite location then merge. I did not replace what you have give me. I just fix the error so don't worry it's the same with your file

Comment: I can't express how I feel at the moment but people like you are what makes the internet a wonderful place.Thank you @cathy

Comment: I'm a selfish person but my parent taught me to give and share than just receiving. In return you will get more blessings in life.

Comment: So, what just happened? Is there anyway that we can download the file as well? I got the same error.

Answer (score 124):

The answer is to add namespaces to your root URLconf. In the mysite/urls.py file (the project’s urls.py, not the application’s), go ahead and change it to include namespacing:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Furthermore, in part 3 of the tutorial [Namespacing URL names](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial03/#namespacing-url-names) the use of *app_name* is mentioned as the accepted way for adding the polls namespace. You can add the line for this in your `polls/urls.py` as follows:

```
app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    ...
]
```

Comment: pay attention to the word "namespace"

Comment: Actually, that's not the recommended way, When you say "polls:..." it looks in two namespaces, the application namespace, and the instance namespace. Setting the "namespace" attribute on a URL adds that router into the instance namespace. Generally you'll just want to use the application namespace, by adding app_name="polls" into polls/url.py. See this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial03/#namespacing-url-names

Comment: Update: my info is correct for django 1.9, but adding the namespace= attribute in the include is the only way prior to 1.9

Comment: I wanted to change the URLs from 'polls' to 'surveys' instead.  Modified `mysite/urls.py` file: `url(r'^surveys/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),` and `polls/urls.py` file: `app_name = 'surveys'`

Answer (score 18):

Following the same Django tutorial and having the same names,
I had to change in `mysite/urls.py`
from:

```
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
```

to:

```
 url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
```

Answer (score 9):

**Django 2.0**

in ***yourapp/urls.py***

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'yourapp'

urlpatterns = [
    path('homepage/', views.HomepageView.as_view(), name='homepage'),
]
```

in ***urls.py***

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('yourapp/', include('yourapp.urls')),
    ]
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to add the following line to the top of the detail.html:

```
{% load url from future %}
```

(Notice you've already used this line in the index.html in order to use the polls namespace)

Comment: Not really relevant anymore. That "load" was required during the transition period between the old-style {% url viewname %} and new style {% url "viewname" %}. Nowadays, since Django 1.5, only new style is allowed and since Django 1.6 (I think) trying to load url from future is an error.

Answer (score 8):

Inside myapp/urls.py add the following module-level attribute:

```
app_name = "polls"
```

This will set the "application namespace name" for that application. When you use names like "polls:submit" in a reverse, Django will look in two places: application namespaces (set like above), and instance namespaces (set using the namespace= parameter in the "url" function). The latter is important if you have multiple instances of an app for your project, but generally it's the former you want.

I had this very issue, and setting namespace= into the url() function seemed wrong somehow.

See this entry of the tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial03/#namespacing-url-names

Update: this information is correct for Django 1.9. Prior to 1.9, adding a namespace= attribute to the include is, indeed, the proper way.

Comment: This is what got me--simply including `polls.urls` does *not* automatically indicate to the Django URL resolver that "polls" is the application namespace.

Answer (score 5):

I think you missed the namespace:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the line:
`{% url 'polls:vote' poll.id %}`
with:
`{% url 'vote' poll.id %}`
worked out for me...

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue.
it is fixed now by adding
 `app_name = "<name of your app>"` in `app/urls.py`

Answer (score 0):

namespace should be added polls/urls.py file.

```
url(r'^myapp/$', include('myapp.urls',  namespace ='myapp')),
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by adding an explanation to it.

Answer (score 0):

**For anyone using "django-hosts":**

I had the same error and for me adding this to my template solved it (without any us of namespace etc.):

```
{% load hosts %}
<a href="{% host_url 'YOUR_URL' host 'YOUR_HOST' %}">Admin dashboard</a>
```

Additionaly I added `PARENT_HOST = 'YOUR_PARENT_HOST'` to my settings.py

[Reference](https://django-hosts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templatetags.html)

Answer (score -2):

The problem is in the tutorial.
While adding the namespace( in your case 'myapp') to your URLconf, the tutorial uses the following code of line:

```
app_name = 'myapp'
```

The Django framework for some reason treats it as a unicode string. Instead please enclose the name of your app in double quotes instead of single quotes.
For example,

```
app_name = "myapp"
```

This will most certainly solve your problem. I had the same problem and doing so solved it.

Comment: I have the same problems now and that certainly did not solve it

Answer (score -4):

Restart the web server. Just that.

Comment: Restarting the web server it won't help.