# Django raises NoReverseMatch: 'en-us' is not a registered namespace

Tags: python, django

Django raises

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'en-us' is not a registered namespace

How i can fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Error u"'polls" is not a registered namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892462/django-error-upolls-is-not-a-registered-namespace)

Comment: Am assuming that you are using Django CMS, you need to check that your language settings in settings.py and CMS si correctly setting up to serve the correct page translations from the urls

Answer (score 2):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39917987/django-1-9-to-1-10-raises-noreversematch-uen-gb-is-not-a-registered-namespace) for a more complete description of why this error is raised.

In a nutshell, if there are import errors while populating URLs you might run in to this error.

Answer (score 0):

NoReverseMatch error has to do with urls so check your url patterns 
url(...). 
make sure your django version is 1.11 if not try to update it to 1.11